Unable to get X-server settings on nvidia-settings
Unable to get X-server settings on Nvidia-Settings panel
Started with an upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS which resulted in the Black Screen of Death.  Resolved by disabling Nouveau.  Now can only use one monitor in a two-monitor system, nvidia-settings does not display any x-server settings to change this.
Digging around for several hours I discover the following interesting items:
    $ sudo ubuntu-drivers install results in an error: 
    Some packages could not be installed... 
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     linux-image-6.8.0-50-generic : Depends: linux-modules-6.8.0-50-generic but it is 
    not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I am on $ uname -r > 6.8.0-49-generic
I was able to install  'sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470' without apparent issues.
But when I try to run nvidia-settings, I get the following error
 ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X server is not accessible. This file should have been installed along with this driver at /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation.


The folder /usr/share/nvidia/ does not exist, although it should have been created when Nvidia 470 was installed.
I have removed and re-installed Nvidia drivers several times in this process, with several sudo apt update, reboots, and so on in between.
I am using Wayland - when I try to boot into X11 server I just get a login loop.
Can't get any x-server settings in Nvidia-Settings.  Any suggestions?
{EDIT] Apparently 6.8.0-50 is broken, maybe fixed soon.  I will come back to this problem in a few days and see if things can be put back together.
Meanwhile:
    $  lspci | grep VGA
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B 
    [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)


The 6.8.0-50 kernel has been kept back. Try again a little later (maybe days).  The modules and modules-extra packages have no candidates for installation yet.

Six hrs. later and the missing module packages are present, and the 6.8.0-50 install works for me.

from the output I gather that your installation is broken, are any kernel modules actually loaded after installation? Why do you want use the 470 version, it seems kind of antiquated unless you have a very old graphics card. What card are you using? Is safe-boot enabled in the UEFI settings? If yes you might disable it or sign your kernel modules.
Have you ever heard of DKMS, this would make sure that after a kernel update new modules are automatically built.

Why do you want use the 470 version, it seems kind of antiquated unless you have a very old graphics card. What card are you using?
I am using a GK208B [GeForce GT 710] and i believe this is the correct driver for it.
I have messed around with safe-boot, that got me past the Black Screen of Death.  I do not know anything about how to use DKMS.
From the other response it sounds like the central problem is that 6.8.0-50 is not ready for prime time.  I will get back to this issue in a few days as the other respondent suggests maybe things will change.

This happened to me yesterday, I also have an NVIDIA card, so I guess there was an issue with the updates.
Try again today, I see I could finally install linux-image-6.8.0-50-generic through updates.

The problem here was broken packages.  Nuked the system and reinstalled fresh to fix it.
